# Python Module to Parse 'GUANO' .wav file metadata

Tags: python

Anyone has suggestions for python module to read the GUANO file metadata generated by Wildlife Acoustics Echo Meter Touch application.

https://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/SCHEMA/GUANO.html

Unfortunately, Guano (https://pypi.org/project/guano/) seems to be unable to properly parse the files generated by this application.

Comment: This seems strange, can you please provide some more details, on how you are using py guano and which errors you are getting. Also version numbers are of importance.

Comment: Using 'guano 1.0.14' with Python 3.10.  


```
from guano import GuanoFile

# load a .WAV file with (or without) GUANO metadata
g = GuanoFile('test.wav')
print(g['Make`])
``

Comment: and what is the error you get? Did you try other tags from the wildlifeacoustics web site (e.g. Timestamp, Samplerate, Tags)?

Comment: Yes, I have tested with SM4Bat sample files and also the ones I have recorded. Checked  I confirm that Py-Guano no longer able to extract metadata.

Comment: Added a testcase and filed a bug report here https://github.com/riggsd/guano-py/issues/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the file in question has the metadata in GUANO format. The test file in your guano-py github bug-report has the metadata formatted in Wildlife Acoustics WAMD format and must first be converted to GUANO:

From https://github.com/riggsd/guano-py/blob/master/bin/wamd2guano.py :

> """ Convert Wildlife Acoustics WAMD metadata files to use GUANO
> metadata instead.
>
> usage::
>
> ```
> $> wamd2guano.py WAVFILE... """
> ```

Suggest to correct your "bug-report" at guano-py github

Comment: Thank you @WMXZ I have been mislead to believe that vendors files are standard compliant GUANO files.